# Azure Media Services: Get the duration of a video that needs to be encoded

Tags: .net, azure, encoding, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

Is it possible to get the duration of a video using Azure Media Services .NET SDK **before** creating an encoding job? I have a requirement to ignore encoding requests if the duration exceeds a threshold. The blob is uploaded with a SAS token, and unfortunately the tokens can't enforce this restriction, so I have to do validation on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, we dont have an API to "probe" a file in storage or at a remote URL.
However... that said, there is a way to do that. I've seen folks build an Azure Function that just hosts FFProbe or MediaInfo.exe to do that really quick.  There may even be samples of that out there that you could find.

For example, here is one we made to use ffmpeg.exe, which you could modify to use ffprobe.exe
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/blob/master/Encoding/Encoding/VodFunctions/ffmpeg-encoding.cs

Comment: Additionally you could kick off an encoding job with Media Services that produces a singe thumbnail.  The result would be the thumbnail itself (not the point of this exercise) and a metadata JSON that has information about the input file including the duration.  Keep in mind that this is not instant though.  It takes a little time for the job to queue and run.

Comment: That is true as well!  
With the FFMPEG path, I think that FFProbe can source from a URL, so you should not have to copy the asset to any location. It should be able to probe a remote URL path using just the SAS URL